# sign up form using spring security

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, sign

I am new to spring, and I have to create a web app using it.
I started with creating a sign in page using spring MVC/security and hibernate, it works great (I followed a tutorial)
Now, I want to create sign up page. I tried to do it using the few skills I've learned, but, still, this doesn't work, error 404.

Can anyone please, suggest a tutorial that can help ? or at least a project directory structure ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Error 404 means Not Found. Check you controller and pages. Just create a simple signup page and save user information in your database. You didn't need any spring security science for signup purpose.

Answer (score 0):

indeed, 404 its a client error, check your controller mapping

but, for a complete exemple you can try the example from spring boot tutorial, working great and easy

https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/